# Is there a way to use Excel VBA to update a filter in powerquery?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

So I have an ODBC dataset that I have filtered in PowerQuery before loading into Excel.

On one of the date columns I have put a filter:

> Keeps rows where 'CREATION DATE' *is after* **date X** AND *before* **date Y**

The dataset is too big for Excel without constantly changing the filters. I would like to use VBA to automatically change the 'is after' and 'before' dates when reloading the query.

The idea is that the variable 'is after' and 'before' dates could be inserted into two cells in Excel. Lets say Sheet1.range("A1") and sheet1.range("A2"). The VBA script would insert these dates in the PowerQuery fields before reloading the query.

Would this be possible? And how?

[Update: Screenshot of PowerQuery menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3iwd.png)

Comment: No need for VBA you can refer to a range in Excel and use it in Power Query to filter whatever you want

Comment: I looked for such functionality but could not find it in the PowerQuery interface. Could you tell me where to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this doesn't require VBA you can leverage Excel Names and Power Query directly.

Steps:

1. Add cell names to `from` and `to` dates in Excel

- Add the from date to a cell and add a name to that cell: `fromDate`
- Add the to date to a cell and add a name to that cell: `toDate`

[image]

2. Add those cells to power query

- Select the cell and click Data | From table/range

[image]

- Change to date type

[image]

- Drill down to the first cell (right click)

[image]

3. Use fromDate and toDate queries in the table date column filter

- You can write the code or use the interface and adapt it: = `Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Date] >= fromDate and [Date] <= toDate))`

[image]

M code:

Table1

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Date] >= fromDate and [Date] <= toDate))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

fromDate

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fromDate"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
    Column1 = #"Changed Type"{0}[Column1]
in
    Column1
```

toDate

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="toDate"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
    Column1 = #"Changed Type"{0}[Column1]
in
    Column1
```

Table1 Query

[image]

fromDate Query

[image]

Check the screencast

[image]

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you for this well made tutorial. I hope to get around to using this very soon and I will let you know whether it worked.

Comment: Awesome if you have any doubts, just ask